# Can a custom flag stay in active state despite being attended to?

Tags: support, comments, flags

I'd raised a custom flag on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21011981/2024761) explaining the moderator to clean-up the comments as they were totally unrelated to the post. There were atleast 8-10 comments and all the comments were related to why the particular post got downvotes and thus the custom flag.

Not sure when a moderator attended to it, but this flag was attended to and all the comments were cleared out. But the strange thing is that, the flag which I had raised is still in active state since `Jan 9 at 5:27`.

Is this possible? Doesn't a flag automatically gets dismissed with an appropriate status after being attended to? Or does the moderator have to explicitly dismiss the flag with an appropriate status? And if this is the case, did the moderator who attended to the flag, somehow missed to dismiss the flag? Am in a bit of a fix here. Can somebody highlight on what just might have happened here?

Comment: Flag gets auto dismissed only if the post itself is deleted. Otherwise the mod must manually dismiss it, as far as I can tell. The system can't possibly know your flag asked to delete comments hence it should be dismissed upon comments deletion. AI is cool, but we don't have it yet. ;)

Comment: That said, probably there was another flag asking to remove the comments so the mod saw it, deleted the comments, dismissed it, and never saw your flag.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - So in that case, my flag would be *declined* whenever another mod attends to it right? Cuz when my flag is gonna be attended to, the moderator would not find any comments to delete at all.

Comment: Mods can see deleted comments so I believe the mod will dismiss it as helpful.

Comment: In the future you can flag one of the comments instead as "Other" then when deleted you can be sure your flag will be auto dismissed. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - That's a very good idea. We can specify the moderator to delete all the comments for that post in the other text of a comment flag also right?

Comment: The only downfall I see is that, I'll be using up my comment flags for such cases instead of saving them up for flagging *spam/offensive/rude* comments.

Comment: Sure, that's what we have the "Other" option for, among other things. That said, comment flags might take longer to be reviewed. As for using your comment flags that's right but we get enough... up to you of course. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just an oversight, I'm sure. The specific problem with bulk deleting comments due to a flag is that it's easy to *forget* to dismiss the flag. The purge all comments option for moderators reloads the page automatically after completing the command, which gives the impression (even to a moderator used to using it) that the flag was automatically taken care of as well, and sometimes we just close out the tab thinking we're done, even though that is not the case and the flag *is* still pending.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Why do I forget that even the moderators are just human ;) And the flag has now been taken care of :)